# Did Airbus do anything about Qantas Flight 72?

Tags: airbus-a330

I recently read about [Qantas Flight 72](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qantas_Flight_72)
I'm wondering if Airbus did anything else besides release an Operators Information Telex? And I'm also wondering if this threat is still possible today? One last question, does the new Airbus A330-900neo and new Airbus A340 BLADE have the same ADIRU system as the other Airbus A330 and Airbus A340 or was something changed or fixed?

Comment: FYI: The BLADE is a [testbed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testbed_aircraft) for laminar wings, it's not a new commercial airplane.

Answer (score 3):

The ADIRUs presently used are totally different:

for exemple the hardware is of different generation bringing their physical dimension about twice smaller.

Todays AIRBUS used ADIRUs manage the GPS received data too. Internally the technical implementation of parameters is different, just due to technology evolution.

Most of these changes are not directly related to Qantas flight 72, but to new technology, for instance data interchange (such as sending the data of a label such as 224 as being the data of another label such as  204) due to a « bit » failure is not likely to happen nowadays as was the case in previous equipments because internally a « bit » failure is nowadays more precisely detected. Thus sending the altitude as being the AOA won’t happen today.